# Are there any online dictionaries that supply IPA transcriptions for Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese, ipa

I know little about Cantonese (for now), but please advise me if I erred in conjecturing that IPA is more precise and helpful than [Yale or Jyutping Romanisations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Cantonese).

Answer (score 2):

[The English Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org) has IPA for Cantonese along with other commonly-used romanization schemes (Jyutping, Yale and Cantonese Pinyin). For example, for the entry on [朋友](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%8B%E5%8F%8B), under "Pronunciation" in the Chinese section, you can click [Expand] to see the IPA /pʰɐŋ²¹ jɐu̯¹³/. There's also IPA for other topolects, like Mandarin (/pʰɤŋ³⁵ i̯oʊ̯³/ → /pʰɤŋ³⁵ i̯oʊ̯³/). (Note: There may be a bug with the audio that covers the IPA.)

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/), with traditional Chinese, English interface.

On the top right corner, you can choose the scheme: IPA (number) & IPA(letter).

Have fun. :)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but I cannot see the IPA transcription even after selecting these options? eg: Where's the IPA on http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%BA%AB?

Comment: when you do a search, in the result page, choose the scheme from top right corner, you should get the "Canton. Syllables", above the sound file, in the middle of the page

:)